# Access to Access Transfer

Tags: php, ms-access, com, adodb

I have asked a couple of questions on here in a rush, and I am getting nowhere fast, I keep changing things and just ending up with a different problem, and no closer to having a clue what is causing it. I am a PHP MYSQL man, and I am having to work with Access via the COM class.

Basically the client has multiple servers, each with an access database, and each with a CMS, the tables should contain the same data and have slipped out of Sync. It is my job to come up with a way of resyncing them.

I have came to bringing the data out into an Array, serializing it and saving it to a file on the main server (the one all should sync to) and then on the other servers, downloading the file, unserializing it and item by item, checking if it is in the DB, and if not inserting it. The insert is failing. I have tried building an sql query for each item and doing $this->conn->Execute(); and that is failing row by row on silly things, so I am now trying this:

```
function syncCMS()
    {
       $this->output['msg'] .= "<p><b>The following properties were added to the database on ." . $this->hsite . "</b></p>";
       $this->get_field_names();
       $this->make_connection(); //assigns connection to $this->conn
        $rs = new COM('ADODB.Recordset');
        $rs->CursorType = 2;
        $rs->CursorLocation = 1;
        $rs->LockType = 4;
        $rs->Open($this->table_name,$this->conn);
        foreach ($this->awayPropertyDetails as $key => $property)
        {
            $this->check_for_property($property['pname']);
            if (!$this->property_exists || $this->mode == "fullSync")
            {
               unset($values);
               $bfields = array("pshow","rent","best", "oda1",  "oda2", "oda3", "oda4", "oda5", "oda6", "odap", "topool","tomountain","tofitness","tosauna"); //stores the yes/no values
               $q = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " (" . $this->dbfields . ") VALUES (";
                foreach ($property as $k => $value)
                {

                    if ($k == "Kimlik") {
                        $value = null;
                    }
                    if ($k == "tarih")
                    {
                        $value = date("d/m/Y");
                        $value = "'" . $value . "'";
                    }
        if (in_array($k,$bfields))
                {
                   if ($value == "")
                   {
                       $value = 'FALSE';
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       $value = 'TRUE';
                   }
                }
                     $rs->fields->$k = $value;
$this->output['msg'] .= $property['pname'] . " added";
                }

        $rs->BatchUpdate();
                $rs->Close();
                $this->conn->Close();
               //$this->download_images($property['OBJECT_NR'],$k);
                //$this->output['msg'] .= "<p>Images added</p>";

            }


       }
$message .= "</ul>";
$this->output['msg'] .= $message;
        $this->sendOutput();
        //print_r($property);*/
    }
```

And getting this:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Unable to lookup `Kimlik': Unknown name. ' in D:\inetpub...

Kimlik is the name of the first field, the Auto Number field, I took it out and the problem shifted to the second field.

Comment: Are you able to use ODBC instead of the COM object?  If so, you might find it easier to [use PDO's ODBC support](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php), which should always be available in Windows builds of PHP.

Comment: I think Charles should prolly present his answer as an Answer.  Using Charles' suggestion will force the asker into "the Access way", which is (though inconvenient) perhaps best in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there with:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name;
if (!$this->property_exists || $this->mode == "fullSync")
            {
               $this->make_connection();
               $rs->Open($sql,$this->conn);
              $rs->addnew();
               foreach($rs->Fields as $field)
               {
                   if ($field->name != "Kimlik")
                   {
                   $rs->Fields[$field->name] = $property[$field->name];
                   }
               }

              $rs->Update();
              $rs->Close();
              $this->conn->Close();

               $msg = $this->download_images($property['OBJECT_NR'],$k);
               $this->output['msg'] .= $property['pname'] . " added<br/>" . $msg . "<br/><br/>";

            }
```